# Trouble in connecting Nodejs Application to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have hosted my Nodejs Application on Google Cloud Platform using App Engine and Hosted a MongoDB Instance on MongoDB Atlas. While I am connecting `MongoDB` from my desktop tools working well. but when I start Nodejs Application on Google Cloud it gives Error:

`(node:12124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [auedbaki-shard-00-02-4omtl.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND auedbaki-shard-00-02-4omtl.mongodb.net auedbaki-shard-00-02-4omtl.mongodb.net:27017]
(node:12124) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`

I know this error only occur when server address is wrong, but I have checked all the things and check on my pc. but it is not working on Google Cloud.
I think this is the problem of firewall rules. Any type of help will be appreciable.

Comment: Could you show a little more of the code that fails? Reformatting your answer to make the errors easier to read would be nice as well.

Comment: Can you still run your application? I sometimes have the warnings like so since I do not put try-catch for a promise. Can you check that you have all error handler for your query

Comment: @MichaelShopsin I have created a repo on Github You can visit that link to check the code. Link :-https://github.com/auedbaki/New_Auedbaki

Comment: @dnp1204 No, I can't use any part of the project. After this error, server not respond to any request. Also i have not used try catch block to handle exception. i have use ES6 Promise in the application.

Comment: @auedbaki I'm not an expert in mongodb but you should follow dnp1204's advice and do some logging using try catch blocks. If you cannot attach a debugger than logging is the only way to find out what is going on. You should also log when you enter key functions and get to critical lines, that way you can figure out roughly where your code stalls. I use the log package from npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/log for my Node.js server; good luck :)